# Perl datastructure with shift/push and fast lookup?

Tags: perl, data-structures

I'm receiving events, and I want to keep track of the last N events, and for any new event, count how many times similar events have occurred in the past (this will in general not happen often).

Thus, I need something with queue semantics (shift/push) as well as fast lookups on a key that is NOT the insertion order.

My current solution, when we care about counting only, is to keep both an array of events and a hash of counts, so that I can increment the appropriate counter on pushes and decrement it on shifts. But that doesn't allow me to keep track of more than counts, and is awkward to generalize.

Another possibility was to place events in generations of K+1 hash tables containing N/K events, keeping track of the order of insertion, and discard the oldest table when the newest one is full. This gives me a tradeoff between a queue with constant shift/push and linear lookups (when K=N), and faster lookups at the expense of at most twice the memory (K=1).

I think something like a linked hash table would have a slightly better behaviour. Does this, or anything with equivalent semantics, exist in Perl?

Comment: If you just want an ordered hash, take a look at [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::IxHash). Can you clarify how you classify a set of events as "similar"? Does "the past" mean "within the last N events" or across all events? If it's "within the last N events", a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) might work better than your K+1 hash tables idea.

Comment: Tie::IxHash sounds good, if you make it an answer i'll accept it. "the past" indeed means "the last N events". I thought about a priority queue but it won't typically allow efficient lookups on something other than the priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an ordered hash, take a look at [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aIxHash). It should at least replace your solution where you keep both an array and a hash.